# Conceptual Question on Maxwell's 3rd Equation in Integral Form

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, conventions, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

$$
\oint_C \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{l} = -\frac{d}{dt} \oint_S \vec{B} \cdot d \vec{A}
$$
where $S$ is a surface and $C$ is its boundary.
Why is there no negative sign in front of the left-hand side? I thought that
$$\xi(\text{or EMF}) = \Delta V = -\int_{initial}^{final} \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{l} $$
instead of $ \int_{initial}^{final} \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{l} $.

Comment: The expression $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ is not a general expression for the electric field. Generally there is a term with $\partial \vec{B}/\partial t$ too. For a closed integration path the gradient part diappears and you only have the latter term.

Comment: @Vladimir Kalitvianski Thank you for your reply. Are you referring to the fact that $ \nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{dt} $, and so that explains why the general expression for $ \vec{E} $ includes $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{dt}$?

Comment: Yes, I do. I also meant this (culr) equation where the potential part drops out.

Comment: So, did the curl equation come first before the integral form of the equation? Was the curl equation used to get to the integral form?

Comment: Both are equivalent statements. Neither came before the other.

Comment: The integral form of the curl(E) equation is an experimental result obtained by M. Faraday.